# std::vector.resize not allocating memory sometimes?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013

It seems like std::vector.resize isn't actually allocating memory sometimes. If I run this piece of code:

```
std::vector<InstanceData> instanceData;
instanceData.resize(meshCount);

float randX = 0.0f;
float randY = 0.0f;
float randZ = 0.0f;

float maxX = 1000.0f;
float maxY = 1000.0f;
float maxZ = 1000.0f;

for(int i = 0; i < meshCount; i++)
{
    randX = (rand() % 100) * 0.01f;
    randY = (rand() % 100) * 0.01f;
    randZ = (rand() % 100) * 0.01f;

    instanceData[i].worldMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(randX * maxX, randY * maxY, randZ * maxZ));
    instanceData[i].color = DirectX::XMFLOAT4(randX, randY, randZ, 1.0f);
}
```

The program sometimes crashes when I build for release but seemingly not when I build for debug. I use Visual Studio 2013 to compile.

If I change the `resize(meshCount)` to `reserve(meshCount)` (or just remove it) and resort to using a temporary InstanceData which I then just fill with data and push into the vector it seemingly doesn't crash.

If I attach the debugger to the release version it gives me this error message:

Unhandled exception at 0x00BB5BCB in path.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Any idea what's going on? Why can't I use `resize`?

EDIT:
Here's InstanceData

```
struct InstanceData 
{
    DirectX::XMMATRIX worldMatrix;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color;
};
```

Comment: You *can* use resize. The problem is most likely somewhere else. You should post a simple test-case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you share the definition of InstanceData?

Comment: `resize` and `reserve` do 2 different (though related) things ...

Comment: I am not sure if this is your case, but XMMATRIX must be 16-byte aligned

Comment: @juanchopanza Of course I _can_ use resize, but it seems like it doesn't allocate memory since I get an exception when I try using it.

The test-case that reproduces the problem would be that above

Comment: @marcin_j That seems like it was it... I did a very beginner mistake and used XMMATRIX instead of XMFLOAT4. That's what I get for being sloppy

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use XMFLOAT4X4 instead of XMMATRIX